# Accessing a data frame by rowname is giving me NA rather than the value I expect

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here is an example.  normal is a dataframe with rownames equal to the month and day of an unspecified year (like "-01-01" for Jan 1). The stats listed are over some range of years.

```
head(normal)

Source: local data frame [6 x 7]

      md    meanA      sdA  meanMax    sdMax  meanMin    sdMin
1 -01-01 40.20556 1.424404 43.20185 1.792473 37.20926 1.575386
2 -01-02 40.33056 1.473267 43.16852 2.527014 37.49259 1.480592
3 -01-03 40.29630 1.645513 43.15926 2.347826 37.43333 1.572662
4 -01-04 40.17222 1.635409 42.85000 2.502623 37.49444 1.512707
5 -01-05 40.33796 1.681560 43.22593 2.486444 37.45000 1.511158
6 -01-06 40.22685 1.767241 42.98704 2.380686 37.46667 1.591779

md
#[1] "-01-01"

normal[1,"meanA"]  
#Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

#      meanA
# 1 40.20556

normal[md,"meanA"]    
#Source: local data frame [1 x 1]

#   meanA
# 1    NA
```

Why won't R take the value of a rowname here as they are all unique?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @DavidArenburg You can pass a character vector to index the rownames attribute of a data frame (`df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)`, `rownames(df) <- LETTERS[1:5]`, `df["A", ]`). The issue here is that the `md` component of `normal` is not the rownames of the `tbl_df` object, and hence the OP is trying to match the rownames attribute against the string `"-01-01"`, which clearly isn't going to work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg +1 Yes, but indexing by `[` should work so a more general explanation is needed: the `md` component here *isn't* the rownames even though it might have been before `dply()` got its hands on it.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Ok, great answer!

Comment: Well dplyr certainly had a chance to deal with it.  Snippets of the code are:library(dplyr)

### Los Angeles 577052.csv is NOAA's number for my request.
LANOAA <- read.csv("577052.csv")
LA <- transmute(LANOAA, ...
normal <- filter(LA, Date >= "1981-01-01" & Date <= "2010-12-31") %>%
         mutate(md = substr(as.character(Date),5,10)) %>%
         group_by(md) %>%...

Comment: I don't think I'm getting the message you guys are sending.  
I think I can use a variant of the "filter" comment from @GavinSimpson using  temp <- normal[normal$md == '-0101',] then get my data from the one row table temp.

Comment: What I don't get is the distinction between a Dataframe and a tbl_df, nor was I expecting dplyr to convert from one to the other.  Is that at the heart of the difficulty?
I'm also reading from @GavinSimpson that the rownames are not the md variable, even though I explicitly said they were. Unfortunately, I neglected to make that explicit in my request for help, so the responders, naturally, assumed that I had not made that setting. Could you confirm again that even though I explicitly set it, it didn't last the dplyr processing.

Comment: @SteveMaguire Then I suggest you do some reading about dplyr, the `tbl_df` object, and the thinking behind the package. I don't know how else to tell you that the `md` column here is *not* the rownames of the `tbl_df` object `normal`. Look closely at the output you showed; at the start of each line is a 1, 2, 3, etc. Those are notionally the rownames of this object. I say notionally bc `tbl_df`s don't have rownames; at best these indices are just row number indicators but they aren't tied to any particular row of *data*. dply takes the original rownames & makes a column of data out of them.

Comment: It is the ideology behind the **dplyr** package not to have rownames. If those rownames contain useful information then they should be a variable in the data. If the rownames aren't useful then why have them? Hence any non-trivial rownames are converted to a variable when you create a `tbl_df` object from a data frame. The indexing `[i, j]` with character vector `i` only works against the rownames of an object. As your `normal` now *doesn't* have rownames you can't index like this. You need to `filter()` on the `md` column.

Answer (score 3):

#### Summary

In short, the values in the `md` column of the object shown are **not** the rownames of the `tbl_df` object, and indexing the rows with a character vector works on the rownames, not an arbitrary component of a `tbl_df` or a `data.frame`.

Also, you seem to think that `normal` is a data frame; it's not, it is an object of class `tbl_df` which only *inherits* from the `data.frame` class. This normally doesn't result in any difference, but `tbl_df` objects, as I mention below, don't have rownames, and any rownames on the original data frame are converted to the first component of the `tbl_df` object.

#### Simple solution

As **@DavidArenburg** mentions in comments to the question, the **dplyr** solution to this question is just to use `filter()` as in:

```
filter(normal, md == md)
```

where the first `md` references the column (component) of the `tbl_df` object with that name and the second `md` references the local character vector containing the string pattern to match on: `"-01-01"`.

#### Longer version

You can't index by arbitrary values like this, with `tbl_df`s nor standard `data.frame`s.

You are required to provide one of the required types of indexing as listed in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing-by-vectors).

You can index the rownames of an object like this, which is what you appear to be trying, but the values in `md` **are not the rownames**; the developers of **dplyr** explicitly move the rownames to be a column in the data set and then set null rownames on the object (which then show up as 1, 2, 3, ..., etc down the left hand side of the output).

To do what you want, you need to get either a logical vector matching `md` against the target `"-01-01"` or the numeric vector of indices for the matches:

```
ind <- normal[, "md"] %in% md
## or: ind <- normal[, "md"] == md is ok here as md is length 1
normal[ind, "meanA"]
```

or

```
ind <- which(normal[, "md"] %in% md)
normal[ind, "meanA"]
```

The latter obviously being an additional redundant step but one which illustrates either type of indexing is OK.